# Is it possible to know which java classes are doing disk IO operations

Tags: java, windows, monitor

I know the Resource Monitor in Windows7 can do such thing.

But I need a monitor on other windows platforms.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know if your Java classes are performing IO or are you really interested in the IO activity of your Java processes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor your own classes, log every method before and after using resource.

Comment: it is an Enterprise application. Huge code base. There are many places access the disk. I want to know where are they. This is for profiling purpose.

Comment: You may have designed the system so that it accesses the disk on a single point(class). My suggestion would be to have a look at AspectJ. Java is a subset of this pl, in other words, you can convert your java project into an AspectJ project.
How it is related to this problem is that if, for example, you want to be notified whenever executeQuery method of the java.sql.Statement class is called. You put a pointcut to the method, and assign a method to be called whenever executeQuery is called.
Since I don't know your system, I'm not sure how applicable this is for you. If it is, google it :).

Answer (score 1):

If all IO operations are done through `java.io.*` or `java.nio.*` you could profile your Java enterprise application for those packages and backtrace from there to show which classes are using them.